# using sqlite how to execute insert or update query in phonegap or $cordovaSQLite(nested transaction )

Tags: sqlite, cordova

Using `SQLite`, how to execute insert or update query in `Phonegap` or `$CordovaSQLite`(nested transaction) ?
This is my JSON

```
"eventTracks": [
{
  "eventTrackId": 8,
  "trackName": "Main Event"
},
{
  "eventTrackId": 9,
  "trackName": "track1"
},
{
  "eventTrackId": 10,
  "trackName": "Track2"
},
{
  "eventTrackId": 11,
  "trackName": "Track3"
},
{
  "eventTrackId": 12,
  "trackName": "Track4"
}
],
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to put the SQLite Statement into an string "INSERT INTO...."

This String you are sending to your database. Please tell us, if the database is located near the phone gap application or is located f.e. in the web.

If(database located in web)

{
You have to know how the database has to get the statements, so that she can excecutet them. If you know this, sending should be easy, because the "how" is defined by the database
}

else
{
Clarify how you can access. In many cases you can create an object "Database" and define an function like excecuteCommands(String com){...}
}